# Load QR Code to another view controller (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, qr-code

I am currently doing a quiz application where a user must scan a QR code to do the 1st question followed by scanning another QR code to the 2nd qn. As of right now, my qr code scanner is only able to scan the qr code to a web url instead. I've already done the layout and buttons for my questions, i only need the qr code to link to my qn controller instead. Thank you in advance.

This is my QRScannerController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var messageLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topbar: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

    let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()

            // Move the message label and top bar to the front
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: topbar)

            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                let url = URL(string: metadataObj.stringValue)!
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is my question1controller

```
import UIKit    
class Quiz1Controller: UIViewController {    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you have data, don't open a URL; perform a segue to the next view controller

Comment: ermm how do u do that for the scannerccontroller? is it by a qr code text?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a helper file to separate scanning the QRCode from the UIViewController. This cleans up your code and enables reusability.

To answer your question. You can changes the method `func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {` to handle the output of the scanned QRCode.

I actually implemented a delegate to return the value from the QRCodeHelper, but you can also call a function without your file.

To do so, create a new function `func qrScanDidScanCode(_ code:String)` and call it in the `captureOutput` like this.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    var QRCode: String?
    for metadata in metadataObjects as! [AVMetadataObject] {
        if metadata.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            QRCode = (metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject).stringValue
        }
    }

    if let qr = QRCode {
        qrScanDidScanCode(qr)
    }
}
```

The qr variable holds the QRCodes value as a String and you can now use it anywhere you like.

If you want to use the QRCodes's String value into your next viewController. Use the segues methods perform and prepare.

In the current UIViewController create a new property: `var selectedQRCode:String?` Set this in the `qrScanDidScanCode()` After setting the selectedQRCode call the performSegue.

In the prepareSegue, do something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
        destination.qrCode = selectedQRCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry tom, i'm quite new to Xcode and i have 10 UIViewController that needs the qrscannercontroller to link to seperately. how can i do that in step-by-step? :(

Comment: If its the same QR code value for every UIViewController you can consider saving it in your UserDefaults.standard.set(qrCode, forKey: "qrCodeValue").